# Docker-Compose Passing command args by .env

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, odoo

I often need to start Odoo server with different arguments.

So in docker-compose.yml, which is versioned, I specified the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:12.0
    command: odoo ${ODOO_ARGS}
```

and created a .env file with:

```
ODOO_ARGS="--update=all"
```

This works well with a single argument, but it doesn't handle multiple arguments. For example if I try the following:

```
ODOO_ARGS="--database=myDb --update=all --stop-after-init"
```

the command will be evaluated as: odoo --database="myDb --update=all --stop-after-init"

I pretty sure it is a syntax issue, so I'd like to know how to pass multiple arguments to the command option through .env file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually evaluates to `odoo "--database=myDb --update=all --stop-after-init"` just because you put quotes in the env file. Here is an example with several arguments in one string:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  test:
    image: debian:buster
    command: find ${ARGS}
```

.env

```
ARGS=/ -name bash
```

Running this you'll get:

```
test_1  | /bin/bash
test_1  | /usr/share/lintian/overrides/bash
test_1  | /usr/share/menu/bash
test_1  | /usr/share/doc/bash
```